# Deployed NextJS app's API returns 404 with NextJS version 13

Tags: next.js

Is there anyone else who faced the issues just like me? I try to make a GET request to my API endpoint it keeps on returning 404 when the application is deployed on Vercel - **it works perfectly fine on locally**.

[image: Get an 404 page while I'd call the api endpoint]

Even it is a simple api that are provided by the Next.JS by default.

**default api location**: pages/api/hello

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
res.status(200).json({
    name: 'John Doe',
})
```

}

**My package.json**

```
{
"name": "my-next-js-sample"
"version": "0.1.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "firebase": "^9.13.0",
    "next": "13.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0"
}
```

}

**This is how I'd structured my folders.**

[image]

**This is how'd called the api routes.**

```
http://localhost:3000/api/hello
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/live
```

Perfectly can call any api routes just like this example in local development.

[image]

**Vercel Project Settings**

[image]

Comment: How do you call the endpoint?

Comment: @omi-shah I'd already checked that place. There is nothing wrong with it. When I'd deployed the vercel choosed as NextJS project by default. :)

Comment: Where have you deployed it, that 404 page looks like sent by your deployed platform

Answer (score 0):

After I'd created a new vercel account and deployed this project into that new one, then the problem has solved without knowing the actual issues.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone crossing with this problem, [this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42812#issuecomment-1313287665) might be your guy

In a nutshell: **Standalone** configuration is not yet supported.